# Missing 'orders' entity from admin panel export

Tags: admin

I only have 'products' and 'customers' as an entity type to export.

There are orders in our system to export.

Why is orders export missing?

Comment: After research I found http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/blue-jalappeno-order-export.html which is a very good free order export tool for Magneto

Answer (score 1):

BY default Magento does not have an order export system in System->Import/Export.
That's all you get: customers and products.
If by any chance you had an extension that did this and it doesn't anymore you should contact the extension provider.